# Шарик в react не движется

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Есть код

```js
import React from 'react';

import './styles/BackGround.scss';
import Star from './Star.js';

class BackGround extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = { mouseCoordinates: {
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
  }};

  this._onMouseMove = this._onMouseMove.bind(this);
 }

 _onMouseMove(e) {
  this.setState({ x: e.screenX, y: e.screenY });
 }

 render(){
  let x = this.state.x / 10, y = this.state.y / 10;

  console.log(x + " " + y);
  return(
   <div className='bg' onMouseMove={this._onMouseMove}>
    <Star size={4} leftIndent={x} topIndent={y}/>
   </div>
  );
 }
}

export default BackGround;
```

и еще код

```html
import React from 'react';

class Star extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
  super(props);

  this.state = {
   values: {
    position: "fixed",
    backgroundColor: "#F0FFFF",
    borderRadius: "50%",
    height: this.props.size + "px", 
    width: this.props.size + "px",
    marginLeft: this.props.leftIndent + "px",
    marginTop: this.props.topIndent + "px",
   },
  }
 } 
 render(){
  return(
   <div style={this.state.values}></div>
  );
 }
}

export default Star;
```

при этом при выполнении шарик который по идеи зависит от положения мыши не движется, хоть и сами координаты выводятся в консоль успешно 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вопрос в том, как исправить эту ситуацию

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В классе Star вы только инициализируете state в конструкторе. Больше он не меняется. Вам вообще не нужен state в классе Star

Сделайте

```
class Star extends React.Component{
    render(){
        let values = {
            position: "fixed",
            backgroundColor: "#F0FFFF",
            borderRadius: "50%",
            height: this.props.size + "px", 
            width: this.props.size + "px",
            marginLeft: this.props.leftIndent + "px",
            marginTop: this.props.topIndent + "px",
        };

        return(
            <div style={values}></div>
        );
    }
}
```